# Recent version of AngularJS broke workings of multiple groups of radio buttons

Tags: angularjs, radio-button

I had a view with multiple groups of radio buttons that worked great, but was using a really old version of AngularJS (v1.0.2 as I was playing with an existing fiddle I had found on the net)

[Example using AngularJS v1.0.2](http://jsfiddle.net/m6q757gh/9/)
[image: v1.0.2]

As soon as I upgraded to v1.4.8, it stopped working as expected - i.e. only the last group of radio buttons in each panel have their applicable radio button checked while all others groups had no radio buttons checked.

[Example with newer version of AngularJS](http://jsfiddle.net/m6q757gh/8/)
[image: v1.4.8]

Has anyone got an idea as to what I may be doing wrong? Any help would be much appreciated. Below is the html involved

```
 <body ng-controller="Channels" class="container-fluid">

 <div ng-if="sections===null">
   Loading...
 </div>

 <div class="panel-group" id="accordion1" ng-if="sections!==null">

     <div class="panel panel-default" ng-repeat="item in sections | orderBy: 'resourceCode'">
       <div class="panel-heading">
         <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign text-primary" style="float: left; margin-right: 5px;"></div>
         <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#{{getID(item)}}">
           <span class="panel-title" ng-bind="item.resourceCode"></span>
         </a>
       </div>
       <div id="{{getID(item)}}" class="panel-collapse collapse" ng-class="{'in': isActiveSection(item)}">

       <table class="table">
         <thead>
           <th class="col-sm-6">Name</th>
           <th class="col-sm-2 text-center">Read</th>
           <th class="col-sm-2 text-center">ReadWrite</th>
           <th class="col-sm-2 text-center">None</th>
         </thead>       
         <tr ng-repeat="subitem in item.subPrivilegeModels | orderBy: 'resourceCode'">
           <td class="col-sm-6"><span ng-bind="subitem.resourceCode"></span></td>
           <td class="col-sm-2 text-center">               
             <input type="radio" name="access_{{$parent.$index}}_{{$index}}" ng-model="subitem.access" ng-value="'READ'"/>                 
           </td>
           <td class="col-sm-2 text-center">
             <input type="radio" name="access_{{$parent.$index}}_{{$index}}" ng-model="subitem.access" ng-value="'READWRITE'"/>
           </td>
           <td class="col-sm-2 text-center">
             <input type="radio" name="access_{{$parent.$index}}_{{$index}}" ng-model="subitem.access" ng-value="'NONE'"/>
           </td>
         </tr>
         <tbody>
       </table>
       </div>
     </div>

   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

not to worry...managed to solve it using a form element between the sections and changed the naming of the radiobuttons

```
<body ng-controller="Channels" class="container-fluid">
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion1" ng-if="sections!==null">

 <div class="panel panel-default" ng-repeat="item in sections | orderBy: 'resourceCode'">
   <div class="panel-heading">
     <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign text-primary" style="float: left; margin-right: 5px;"></div>
     <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#{{getID(item)}}">
       <span class="panel-title" ng-bind="item.resourceCode"></span>
     </a>
   </div>
   <div id="{{getID(item)}}" class="panel-collapse collapse" ng-class="{'in': isActiveSection(item)}">
   <form>
   <table class="table">
     <thead>
       <th class="col-sm-6">Name</th>
       <th class="col-sm-2 text-center">Read</th>
       <th class="col-sm-2 text-center">ReadWrite</th>
       <th class="col-sm-2 text-center">None</th>
     </thead>       
     <tr ng-repeat="subitem in item.subPrivilegeModels | orderBy: 'resourceCode'">
       <td class="col-sm-6"><span ng-bind="subitem.resourceCode"></span></td>
       <td class="col-sm-2 text-center">               
         <input type="radio" name="access_{{$index}}" ng-model="subitem.access" ng-value="'READ'"/>                 
       </td>
       <td class="col-sm-2 text-center">
         <input type="radio" name="access_{{$index}}" ng-model="subitem.access" ng-value="'READWRITE'"/>
       </td>
       <td class="col-sm-2 text-center">
         <input type="radio" name="access_{{$index}}" ng-model="subitem.access" ng-value="'NONE'"/>
       </td>
     </tr>
     <tbody>
   </table> 
   </form>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```